# Sending mail with ip

Tags: javascript, html

I have above script, i want to send email with remote ip address

but am getting error that ip address not defined

`this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: ip is not defined`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sending Mail</title>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
    <script>
        function getIP(json) {
            var ip = ("public IP address which is: " + json.ip);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            Email.send({
                Host: "smtp host",
                Username: "smtp username",
                Password: "12345",
                To: 'recpt',
                From: "from",
                Subject: "hey",
                Body: `My ip is: ${ip}`,
            }).then(
                message => alert(message)
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="button" value="Send Mail" onclick="sendEmail()" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Declare `ip` outside of the `getIP` function so your `sendEmail` function has access to it

Comment: change `${ip}` to `${json.ip}`

Comment: also, what's the point of using multiple script tags?

Comment: @Giuppox — Neither `json` nor `ip` are defined in that scope so that change won't help.

Comment: i tried that but this error i get Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: @Quentin ow, I just thought that the `json` object was provided by that `api.ipify.org ` api

Comment: @Giuppox — It is: As an argument to the JSONP callback so it is scoped to that function.

Comment: i fixed it, and sending but delivering ip undefined that means it cant  pick it